# Django, optgroup, вывод категорий и подкатегорий

Tags: python, django, циклы

Как вывести подкатегории, отсосящиеся только к данной категории? Вот как это выглядит сейчас:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_text


class SubCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subcategory_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subcategory_text
```

views.py:

```
class AdCreate(CreateView):
    subcategories = SubCategory.objects.all()
    model = Ad
    fields = ['city', 'category', 'ad_title', 'ad_text', 'img']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        create = super(AdCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        create['subcategories'] = self.subcategories
        return create
```

form.html:

```
<div class="col-75">
    <select id="category" name="category">
        {% for category in subcategories %}
            <optgroup label="{{ category.category }}">
                <option value="{{ category.id }}">{{ category.subcategory_text }}</option>
            </optgroup>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно обойтись одной моделью Category, а именно

```
class Category(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(self, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    category_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
def __str__(self):
    return self.category_text
```

Таким образом сокращаем кол-во моделей и получаем возможность создавать подкатегорию для подкатегории и т.д. :) Главные категории будут те у которых parent=None. Далее во view проходим рекурсивно по главным категориям и формируем иерархию.

Если отвечать на вопрос прямо то нужно в view которая отвечает за рендеринг файл form.html сделать фильтрацию по типу

```
subcategories = SubCategory.objects.filter(category=<нужная_категория>)
```

и передать subcategories в рендер

```
return render(request, 'form.html', {'subcategories': subcategories})
```